# Is it acceptable to offer rep bounty in advance?

Tags: discussion

Take a scenario where I have a question , and I write something like this at the end of it :

"I'll reward the correct answer with +100rep".

I do this before I get the option to offer a bounty (obviously).

Is something like this acceptable?

Comment: It is *very* inappropriate, your question is not more important than anybody else's.  You get quick answers by asking a well-documented question, if it takes more than 15 minutes then you did it wrong and it's going to take a week.

Comment: If you do add that to your question, you can certainly expect someone to come along and edit your question to remove it. It's noise and not germane to the content of the question.

Comment: Why spend 100 rep if it's possible to get a good and correct answer for zero rep. Quite honestly, I've seen questions that employed your scheme and it makes me want to answer them even less. I find the most appropriate close vote I can and move on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really, no.  Bounties aren't really meant to be used like that.

Give the community a couple of days to answer your question (if it's on-topic and concise enough), and if no one does reply, you can put a bounty on it then, per the normal bounty rules.  Announcing that you will award an answer with a bounty is noisy at *best* and doesn't accomplish much of anything.